# Holy Water Elemental?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

I'm playing an 11th-level Cleric and I just picked up the [Bowl of Commanding Water Elementals](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4592-bowl-of-commanding-water-elementals) in my game after a crazy encounter. During our downtime, I was thinking of using the [ceremony](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ceremony) spell to try and make my [Water Elemental](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17051-water-elemental) friend into a "Holy Water Elemental". Is this possible? I think it's a cool and creative idea, but I don't know if I can do it.

Comment: In Dnd 5e.....?

Comment: Using ceremony to bless water, a bowl of commanding water elementals, this loks like D&D 5e to me.

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for additional help. Really cool idea, even if it does not work by the rules.

Comment: It would be fun as hell fighting against demons/undeads etc. Every cleric should not leave home without one. :D

Answer (score 11):

#### A water elemental is not a vial of water.

*Ceremony* states:

> **Bless Water.** You touch one vial of water and cause it to become holy water.

A water elemental is not a vial of water. The idea here is that *the spell description is the spell's effect*. We see in the rules for spells:

> Each spell description in Chapter 11 begins with a block of information, including the spell’s name, level, school of magic, casting time, range, components, and duration. *The rest of a spell entry describes the spell’s effect.*

Anything not written in the spell description is not an effect of the spell. We also in the spellcasting rules for targets:

> A spell’s description tells you whether the spell targets creatures, objects, or a point of origin for an area of effect (described below).

*Ceremony* tells you what it targets: a vial of water, not a creature, and a water elemental is a creature.

Of course, the DM may let you do this, but by the book, this doesn't work, and there are no rules for what happens if the DM allows it.

Comment: I feel like there IS a workaround though. The bowl needs to be full of water before it can be used - I suppose there's nothing really stopping you from creating (n) vials of holy water to fill it up. Not that it would end up being anything but flavor anyway, unless they homebrew a Holy Water Elemental differently from a Water Elemental.

Comment: @TheLittlePeace Sure there are countless ways you could homebrew or houserule it. You are limited only by your imagination and your DM.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds amazing, but even though I as a DM would probably allow it the elemental only lasts for 1 hour, and ceremony takes 1 hour to cast, so you would end up with a slightly damp patch of holy water.

To do this properly you would need to bind the elemental (planar binding) or cast ceremony faster (chromurgy can do it, but that's broken).

That said, RAW you summon a water elemental, which is a creature rather than actually animated water and has a specific stat block, so you wouldn't be able to do something like this without a lenient DM.

Comment: This seems right, unfortunately @Zinoma. The only way I could imagine swinging anything like this is a pretty dubious stretch. Not worth a a separate response. But, supposing the PC got a bunch of clerics together  and all of them started casting ceremony (at the expense of hundreds, if not thousands, of silver pieces). As the ceremony casting concludes, PC speaks the command word for the *Bowl of Commanding Water Elementals*, and the clerics all target the water elemental. Definitely not covered by RAW as far as I know. But, something to consider.

Comment: Terribly situational. You'd probably only be able to do this if you were were expecting an assault on a monastery to begin in approximately 1 hour.

Comment: @nonymous last week a party I was part of had exactly that situation oddly enough! And we had barrels of holy water! I don't think any of even thought about using it in any way though, I know I didn't.